# Css onclick easter egg

Tags: css, button

Im trying to have a small, hidden button somewhere on the website i am making for a project at school, and i want the button to make the page go absolutely crazy. i already have the code to make it go crazy, i just dont know how i would "bind" it to a button. Or a konami code, that would work, too.

CSS

```
body, p, h1, div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-name: example;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
/* Standard syntax */
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
0%   {background-color:red; left:20%; top:20%; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-90deg) rotateY(360deg);}
25%  {background-color:yellow; left:80%; top:20%;-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(0deg);}
50%  {background-color:blue; left:80%; top:80%;-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-90deg) rotateY(0deg);}
75%  {background-color:green; left:20%; top:80%;-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(0deg);}
100% {background-color:red; left:20%; top:20%;-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-90deg) rotateY(0deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
0%   {background-color:red; left:20%; top:20%;transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-90deg) rotateY(360deg);}
25%  {background-color:yellow; left:80%; top:20%;transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(0deg);}
50%  {background-color:blue; left:80%; top:80%;transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-90deg) rotateY(360deg);}
75%  {background-color:green; left:20%; top:80%;transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(0deg);}
100% {background-color:red; left:20%; top:20%;transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ-(-90deg) rotateY(360deg);}
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm really contributing to this, but instead of a button, how about the konami code? http://code.snaptortoise.com/konami-js/

Comment: @BenHarrison That also sounds pretty fun to try, but i still would have no idea on how to imploment that.. still pretty new to the whole coding aspect.

Comment: You can mess with dynamically loading external CSS or just prepend your selectors with a class name (e.g. `body.egg`) and make the button add such class. In both cases you'll possibly need JavaScript.

Comment: Since it sounds like you're just starting out, now is a great time to begin learning. Your question asked how to bind a button with CSS. You would actually use Javascript to do that. My recommendation would be to learn HTML, CSS, and Javascript (in that order). There are a ton of free and great references online to walk you through that. In the end you'll have a much better understanding of their specific areas of responsibility. Then adding a button, or any other event for that matter, will be a very simple task with your new skills. Good luck!

Comment: The CSS will always apply to the elements that qualify. So the `body, p, h1, div` elements on the page will always get that (crazy) CSS applied to them. You can make you CSS a bit specific and then _make_ some elements qualify as crazy on user's will (click). Making CSS specific is done by introducing `class` or `id` selector in CSS, and click listeners are added using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `jQuery` or `JS`. You could add an `onClick` function to your button

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with your CSS, otherwise the animations will start when the page loads. By that I mean, use these selectors:

```
body.crazy, p.crazy h1.crazy ,div.crazy
```

Then add the crazy class when the button is clicked:

```
$('#egg').click(function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('crazy');
        $('p').toggleClass('crazy');
        $('h1').toggleClass('crazy');
        $('div').toggleClass('crazy');
    }
);
```

Use whatever HTML you like:

```
<button id="egg">
Click me
</button>
```

And a complimentary fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/60komy0d/2/

Answer (score 0):

Make the animation a class - i.e. `.example { animation styles here }` - with all of the animation styles inside it. Then create a click event that adds the class to all elements you want to have the animation:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  $('body, p, h1, div').toggleClass('example');
}
```

You can find good documentation around css animations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Here's a [quick example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKaGzr) of how to use a click event.